# JS Error for Existing Method Check for Adobe DTM?

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

We have been using this code to load the Adobe DTM "pageBottom" method for approx 3 yrs. without issue:

```
    (function () {
        function w() {
            window._satellite ? _satellite.pageBottom() : setTimeout(w, 100)
        }
        setTimeout(w, 300)
    })()
```

It is a function at the bottom of our bootstrap loader file. For some reason, within the past few months, it has been throwing an error of **Uncaught Type Error: _satellite.pageBottom() is not a function at w (wrapper.min.js:[line number]**. I have no idea why?  The method exists. If you want to see this in action, go to www.bankofthewest.com. I was wondering how I should approach this?

Comment: This is an unsupported dtm implementation. Not sure how much help you will get. Certainly none from Adobe.

Comment: @Crayon Violent - I agree but unfortunately, I inherited it and can't change it due to 3rd party application support.

Answer (score 2):

Hm, I'm not sure if this even IS "unsupported"- I've certainly seen plenty of folks do a check to make sure _satellite exists to prevent errors when running _satellite.pageBottom, though the timeout does complicate that a little. 
It's hard to tell what's going on because your DTM library isn't served up a standard way, but I DO see this in the console: 
"Error, missing Report Suite ID in AppMeasurement initialization".
I'd check a couple things:
1) If you inactivate your Adobe Analytics tool (JUST IN STAGING- this is just an experiment to isolate your variables), does that pageBottom error go away? If so, then it's not actually a pageBottom error, it's caused by some of your Adobe Analytics tool set up
2) Double check that you ARE setting your report suite ID in your Adobe Analytics tool setup. 
Hope that helps!

Comment: This is definitely unsupported. Wrapping `_satellite.pageBottom` in a condition to check if it exists first is okay because it remains syncronously executed in the blocking script tag. Wrapping it in a timeout causes it to no longer be a blocking script tag, which screws with ability to `document.write` sync configured rules, and possibly even DOM Ready or Window Load rules, depending on timing. Having said that, I do not think this is the root of his issue.

Comment: Also, the missing rsid error is a message signifying that no value was passed to the `new AppMeasurement()` call. As long as `s.account` is set with something, tracking should be okay. So maybe `s.account` is not set and AA does not track, but this too is a separate issue from what was described above.